# How can I include my folder header in my index.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2, lamp

I'm developing a web application with apache2 and mySQL using LAMP.

I have a basic page index.php and i would like to include my header.php file located in 'header_footer/header.php'

I tried using `<?php include("./header_footer/header.php");?>` but it doesn't work. 
It works when i put the header.php file in the same folder as my index.php with `<?php include("./header.php");?>` but i would like to have it in a different folder.

Does anyone have an idea why it's working on one case but not on the other ?

Comment: Either go straight to root/folder/file, or use `../` depending on the file's location. There are other ways but off the top of my head, that comes to mind.

Comment: if you want to go back one folder you need to use ../ not ./

Comment: lol Funk, you beat me to it hehe

Answer (score 0):

See:

[include path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

[ini.core:ini.include path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

After It is configured problem is solved with:
include("../header_footer/header.php");